# Parse SDK Flutter- Database query to get pointer/ relation field data

Tags: flutter, back4app

I am developing a Task Management app in flutter and I am using Parse SDK for the backend.

How to fetch data of pointer/ relation columns in a query?

My setup:

I have 4 Classes

1. User: this is parse user with the username, email, and password
2. Categories:  columns--> cat_name ( name of this category)
3. Task: below are the columns-
   task_name ( name of this task ) and
   task_cat (this is a pointer to Category class)
4. Activities: Below are the columns:
   userID ( a pointer to User class )
   taskId: ( a pointer to Task Class )
   startTime ( DateTime )
   endTime ( DateTime)
   activityNotes ( String )
   activityDuration( Number)

I am running the following code:

```
await ParseObject('Activities').getAll();
```

And I am getting the following response:

> [{"className":"Activities","objectId":"F7TviWDd1H","createdAt":"2021-02-17T07:21:33.723Z","updatedAt":"2021-02-18T08:59:51.649Z","startTime":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2021-02-17T06:21:00.000Z"},"endTime":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2021-02-17T07:21:00.000Z"},"userID":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"1tHoCAv1QW"},"taskID":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Tasks","objectId":"MFC2oMP2wL"},"activityNotes":"This
> is a Test
> Activity","activityDuration":11234000,"ACL":{"*":{"read":true}}},
> {"className":"Activities","objectId":"5dNxryEGdi","createdAt":"2021-02-17T08:50:58.480Z","updatedAt":"2021-02-18T08:59:58.736Z","startTime":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2021-02-17T04:50:00.000Z"},"endTime":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2021-02-17T06:50:00.000Z"},"userID":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"1tHoCAv1QW"},"taskID":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Tasks","objectId":"rghVxYA6BX"},"activityNotes":"This
> is another test
> activity","activityDuration":33456000,"ACL":{"*":{"read":true}}} ]

My query:

**How can I get the username, task_name, and cat_name associated with an activity in a single query??**

Comment: Have you tried the `includeObject` function?

Comment: Yes, I did try the code:     **QueryBuilder<ParseObject> queryActivities =
        QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject('Activities'))
          ..includeObject(['Tasks']); **       the response is still same

Comment: What are the CLP/ACLs that you have in place for the classes/objects that you want to include?

Comment: ACL and CLP on classes User and Tasks are "read: public" & "write: authenticated"

Comment: One more thing. It should be actually `QueryBuilder<ParseObject> queryActivities = QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject('Activities')) ..includeObject(['taskID']);` Could you please try with that?

Comment: Tried QueryBuilder<ParseObject> queryActivities = QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject('Activities')) ..includeObject(['taskID']); But the response is same:

{"className":"Activities","objectId":"F7TviWDd1H","createdAt":"2021-02-17T07:21:33.723Z","updatedAt":"2021-02-18T08:59:51.649Z","userID":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"1tHoCAv1QW"},"taskID":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Tasks","objectId":"MFC2oMP2wL"},

Comment: Could you please double check if MFC2oMP2wL really exists in Tasks class?

Comment: Yes, it exists.